# Error in creation of vector of objects

Tags: c++, object, vector

I'm making with some classmates a project for the analysis of the performances of a Clos Network, in C++. We encountered the following problem:

```
static const int dim = 3;
packet **pack;
pack = new packet*[dim];
for (int i=0; i<dim; i++)
    pack[i]=new packet();
```

These few lines generate this error messages

[image]

Comment: what are you trying to achieve with this code? when you have more than one "*" in c++ you are doing something wrong. You are using C++11? use smart pointers, not raw pointers.

Answer (score 0):

The first obvious thing I see from the compiler errors it looks like it does not recognise `packet` as a type.

The next thing that strikes me is that these errors are being generated from a file called "event.h" and not a compilation unit. Is your code in a header file?
That code does not belong in one but should be in a compilation unit. We cannot see the context around it. It belongs in a function, not a class definition.

The class "packet" needs to also be a complete type, not forwardly declared.

You should however of course be using vector as in `std::vector` and manage the pointers in it a `shared_ptr` or `unique_ptr` if you are not going to have a vector of objects, i.e. `vector<packet>`

Presumably, `packet` is defined in a header. The compilation unit with the code in your sample needs to include that header.

Comment: Packet was created in this way
    class packet
{
public:


 packet();
 ~packet();
 int in, out;
 double tempo;
 double get_time();
 int get_in();
 int get_out();

 void inizializza();


};

Comment: Yes but if it is defined in a header, is your compilation unit including that header?

Comment: Yes it is :(
I'm using CodeBlocks however, in case it's useful to know

Comment: Your code above is in a header? Your compiler errors are pointing to a file called "event.h"

Comment: Yes, the errors are in the header event.h, which include the packet.h file header

Comment: Why are they in a header? Is it an inlined function or a class definition? The code above can only go in a function.